# HTML Email Styling Issue

Tags: html, css, email

I have the current HTML email template to go out automagically to end user.

But the email that arrives seems to be formatted incorrectly..

Here is HTML code I have:

```html
<div style="background-color: #eeeeef;padding: 50px 0">
<table style="max-width: 640px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 40px 30px 30px 30px" align="center" bgcolor="#366796">
<h1 style="color: #fff"><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif">You've been sent a job opportunity</h1>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="260">
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif">%EMAIL_YOUR_EMAIL% thought you might be interested the following role, currently being advertised on <a href="https://#/">#</a></td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 10px 0 0 0"><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif"><strong>%EMAIL_POST_TITLE%</strong> advertised by %EMAIL_POST_AUTHOR%</td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 10px 0 0 0"><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif">%EMAIL_POST_CONTENT%</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p style="text-align: center"><a href="%EMAIL_PERMALINK%"><img class="aligncenter size-thumbnail wp-image-4019" src="#" alt="APPLY NOW" width="150" height="52" /></a></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #ffffff;padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px">
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr style="text-align:center">
<td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px">
<p style="text-align: center">© %EMAIL_BLOG_NAME%, 2017</p>
<p style="text-align: center"><a href="#/"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-3163 size-full" src="#" alt="logo" width="160" height="34" /></a></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Which should include a grey background behind the email. But when recipient receives the email it doesn't include the grey background.. o_O

[Here is an image showing the issue I'm facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USR3Y.jpg)

Does anyone have any ideas / can help? :)

Comment: Can I add, I've just checked this email on my Crackberry and seems to be displaying correctly, may just be an issue with Outlook

Comment: Yes, outlook has weird issues with backgrounds ;) Add background-color to each cell and the table fore best results.

Comment: Thanks Rachel, I have just looked across various different platforms and outlook seems to be the odd one out. Table styling seems to be fine, Outlook seems to be having issues with the div background :/

Comment: See here for a nice list of compatible styles and email clients: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've checked this in Outlook. Have you tried another email client like Gmail? Outlook pretty much always makes emails look a bit different from how they're coded. I use Robly for work and those emails are always slightly different in Outlook compared to every other email client.

Comment: Thanks Chaniqua, I have checked across a few different platforms and outlook seems to be the problem child

Answer (score 0):

Try to include everything in a `table` with your preferred background color and not in a `div`.

From this article: https://www.arclab.com/en/amlc/how-to-change-background-color-html-newsletter.html

#### How to change the Background Color of a Message?

- Locate the `body` tag and add/change the background color: e.g. `<body bgcolor="#FF0000">` The color code is HEX #RRGGBB.
- Many templates use a background table, because **some clients are cutting out the body tag**. Make sure you change the color for the background table, too.

```html
<body bgcolor="#eeeeef" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" offset="0" topmargin="0">
<!-- background table -->
<table bgcolor="#eeeeef" id="bgtable" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
            <!-- container 600px -->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <p>Hello World!</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- container 600px -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- background table -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created some newsletter, I recommend you to use [Foundation framework to email template](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/getting-started.html) so you can create code cross email clients, also you can test you template in different clients and resolution with [Litmus](https://litmus.com/)